# Cypher Query to Aggregate Relationship Properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j graph containing PI and officer nodes, with relationships between them (each of which has an institution property). I'm trying to create an inst_list property for each PI which lists all the institution properties of all of their edges. I'm still learning my way around Cypher, but confused as to why this is only creating an empty array for each PI:

```
MATCH (p:pi:DOE)-[a:award]-(o:officer:DOE)
WITH pi, a, COLLECT(distinct a.instituion) as insts
SET pi.inst_list=insts
```

It seems like it is an issue with COLLECT, as

```
MATCH (p:pi:DOE)-[a:award]-(o:officer:DOE)
WITH a.institution AS insts
RETURN insts
```

returns all the expected values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove the `a` from your WITH clause.

```
MATCH (p:pi:DOE)-[a:award]-(o:officer:DOE)
WITH p, COLLECT(distinct a.institution) as insts
SET pi.inst_list=insts
```

By including the `a`, you were not collecting the `institution` property for each `p`, you were collecting it for each `p` and `a`, essentially doing nothing.

I also assume you meant `p` and not `pi`; in your query above, `p` is the identifier and `pi` is one of the labels. You also had a typo in `institution`, which is probably why your array was empty instead of the single value.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, the network structure is actually a bit more complex so I didn't copy and paste the real query. Either way, removing 'a' from the 'WITH' statement totally did the trick, thanks!